# How can I improve cardinality estimates on staging tables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-performance, sql-execution-plan

I support a process that runs every night and looks at various clients that have invoices with unpaid line items. The process starts with deleting all records from a staging table and then inserting a number of invoices line items into the staging table.  The process run on a per-client basis, so some clients may have 200 line items, some clients may have 50,000.  We are constantly having issues with the process running an exorbitant amount of time. The issue seems to stem from an inability for SQL server to estimate the correct number of rows that are in the staging table at the time and therefore is generating a bad execution plan.  My question is, is there a way to manually set the estimated number of rows to improve cardinality estimates for the stored procedures involved? Perhaps this could be done through a select count(primaryKey) at the beginning of the run, right after the current runs staging table is populated?

Comment: If you're deleting and inserting and not selecting from the staging table; why would the SQL ever use the stat data from the staging table?  Maybe I'm missing something; but unless you're doing a select or merge and basing the insert/delete based on data in the staging table, why would it's statistics matter?  Or are you talking after delete/insert is done you're then doing analysis on staging table which is slow?  Have you tried a force update on the table/index view? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-updatestats-transact-sql

Comment: You could try updating the statistics on the table before the process starts. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/update-statistics-transact-sql. After updating the statistics, you could recompile any stored procedures to force SQL to come up with a new execution plan. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-recompile-transact-sql

Comment: Deleting all the rows and repopulating it will cause stats to be updated anyway. Probably you are encountering parameter sniffing where different clients have vastly different number of rows but the plan is just compiled for the first one encountered. In which case adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the problem queries will help.

Comment: Parameter sniffing was definitely one of the culprits.  If you want to write an answer I can mark it.

Answer (score 1):

You are executing big batch processes on this table. It's a good approach to delete all indexes before your batch and create them again after the batch.

If you do this, your statistics will be updated and won't be the cause of your problem.

Pay heed also to more generic information about statistics: The update statistics changed a lot between SQL Server 2014 and SQL Server 2016. If you are running SQL Server 2016, you need to check if your database is using the new cardinality estimator created for SQL Server 2016. Just check if your database is running with SQL Server 2016 compatibility level.

If you are running SQL Server 2014, a good option is to enable the trace flag 2371. This trace flag improves the criteria SQL Server uses to automatic update statistics. You should use SQL Server Configuration Manager to enable this trace flag.

However, if you follow the first suggestion, deleting and creating the indexes, the other two suggestion will have low or none impact.

Comment: Why delete & recreate indexes instead of disabling & rebuilding them?

Comment: Sql Server 2008.

Comment: @alroc If you disable the clustered index the table will become read only.

Comment: Why would you delete and re create the indexes rather than just updating statistics.  Wouldn't this create a lot of overhead?

Comment: Rather, what's the additional benefits gained other than triggering a statistics update of deleting and index and re-creating it.